# Google Play Games Leaderboards - Scores Disappear

Tags: android, google-play-games

I have successfully published Google Play Leaderboards on my game.

Problem is, although all scores get saved successfully and permanently, the users cannot see other players' scores, even in All-Time and Public. They appear for a while if recently posted, and then later disappear automatically !

How/Why does this happen, what should I do/check to fix this?

Please help, Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I had as similar issue and ended up disabled fraud score detection and the scores started showing up and staying.

Comment: What was eventually the issue? It seems that I have run into a similar situation, my post is here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37099493/android-games-leaderboard-broken-while-testing I disabled also the tamper protection from the Play console, but the problem still persists!

Comment: I had a new issue happen where permissions switched up and made all players scores super private by security settings which I never solved. Because of the issue, which started happening with all my projects (w/o any code changes), I switched to using "DreamLo.com" for leader boards.